# AES encryption issue: "ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length"

Tags: python, utf-8, base64, aes

I was trying to encrypt some sensitive data inside the database using AES by this python code

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
import pymysql
import os
import hashlib    

def encryption(self, tableName):
    # opening db connection
    db_connection = self.getMySqlConnection()
    cursor = db_connection.cursor()

    print("\tTwo Way Encryption")

    # hashing
    cursor.execute("SELECT toMask FROM " + tableName + ";")
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    for item in row:
        string = str(item[0])
        padded = string.rjust(80)
        secret_key = self.key
        cipher = AES.new(secret_key, AES.MODE_ECB)
        encoded = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(padded))
        encoded = encoded.decode('utf-8')
        stmt = "update " + tableName + " set toMask = '" + encoded + "' where toMask =\"" + string + "\";"
        cursor.execute(stmt)
        db_connection.commit()

    # closing db connection
    db_connection.close()

    print("\tDone")
```

But my data contains some special characters like this

> Å

So I am getting this error:

`ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length`

How can I solve this? Other input string doesn't make any issues.

Or do I need to convert that to any other encoding?

Comment: 1. It makes debugging harder when you nest function calls instead of using intermediate statements and variables. 2. What is the language and what AES library are you using?

Comment: The language is python and the library is Crypto.cipher

Answer (score 0):

The `Crypto.cipher` [documentation](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher.AES-module.html) is incomplete, it does not specify how padding is handled. The guess is that it expects the caller to do the padding. (Please if you write open source provide expected functionality and fully document. In this case PKCS#7 padding should be supported and the input types should be specified (binary, character string, hex, Base64).)

It also seems to require bytes in: `cipher.encrypt(b'Attack at dawn')`, notice the **b**.

Because you must pad and supply binary in you must first convert to binary and then pad so the input to `cipher` is a multiple of the block size (16-bytes for AES).

Null padding is not good is there data man ever have a 0x00 byte as the last byte, the general padding is [PKCS#7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7).

## Rant:

Please if you write open source provide expected functionality and fully document. In this case PKCS#7 padding should be supported and the input types should be specified (binary, character string, hex, Base64, etc).

Comment: `b'Attack at dawn'` refer to a bytes not a binary. Basically, the **b** refer to bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to my question. I'm sharing this for the benefit of any other colleagues who may face this issue.

Actually, there is a difference in encoding with these data. So what I have done is, encoded the string into utf-8 before padding. Then pad it with multiple of 16 and then encrypt the data. After that I decode it and update it to the database. In this way, the problem solved for me.

So the code looks like this:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
import pymysql
import os
import hashlib

    def encryption(self, tableName, paddingLength):
    # opening db connection
    db_connection = self.getMySqlConnection()
    cursor = db_connection.cursor()

    print("\tTwo Way Encryption")


    # hashing
    cursor.execute("SELECT toMask FROM " + tableName + ";")
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    for item in row:
        string = str(item[0])
        #convert to string 
        strng = str(string)
        #encode to utf-8
        string = string.encode('utf-8')
        #pad with length 80
        padded = string.rjust(80)
        secret_key = self.key
        cipher = AES.new(secret_key, AES.MODE_ECB)
        encoded = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(padded))
        #decode utf-8
        encoded = encoded.decode('utf-8')
        encoded = str(encoded)
        # deselect strict mode
        cursor.execute("SET @@global.sql_mode= 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';")
        stmt = "update " + tableName + " set toMask = \"" + encoded + "\" where toMask =\"" + strng + "\";"
        # print(stmt)
        cursor.execute(stmt)
        db_connection.commit()

    # closing db connection
    db_connection.close()
    print("\tDone")
```

So just by encode it to utf-8 solve the issue.